# Various iterations of snakefile give the same error

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, snakemake

I am trying to use snakemake for a bioinformatics pipeline. To test it, I made the following snakefile.

I have a directory with various fastq.gz files (e.g. K1_R1.fastq.gz, K1_R2.fastq.gz, K2_R1.fastq.gz etc) and I am running fastqc on them.

```
SAMPLES = [ "K1", "K2", "W1", "W2" ]
REPLICATE = ['R1', 'R2']

PathtoWD = '/home/hbanduk/scratch/working_projects_2020/'

rule fastqc:
    input:
        "expand(PathtoWD + "/raw_data/{sample}_{replicate}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES, replicate=REPLICATE)"
    output:
         PathtoWD + "/fastqc_raw_reads/{sample}_{replicate}_fastqc.zip",
         PathtoWD + "/fastqc_raw_reads/{sample}_{replicate}_fastqc.html"
    shell:
        "fastqc {input} -o /home/hbanduk/scratch/working_projects_2020/fastqc_raw_reads"
```

when I run,

```
snakemake -np snakefile
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError in line 9 of 
/scratch/hbanduk/working_projects_2020/Snakefile:
invalid syntax
```

I have tried many permutations of this file but I keep getting the same error (othertimes for other lines).

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're using double quotes within doubles quotes "" -- use single quotes or tripple quotes somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Chris_Rands' point about double quotes within double quotes should fix the syntax error, but you probably want to remove the quotes around `expand()` altogether. I.e.:

```
expand(PathtoWD + "/raw_data/{sample}_{replicate}.fastq.gz", sample=SAMPLES, replicate=REPLICATE)
```

Instead of

```
"expand(...)"
```